Regex for Password with repetitive pattern
I have a requirement for password with below requirements, out of which all fulfilled, except repeated words/patterns.

At least 1 digit
At least 1 upper case
At least 1 lower case
At least 1 special character
No repeating chars (AA not valid, 11 not valid)
No repeating words or pattern (ProPersonPro or xyzxyz) - Unable to implement (within same regex)

This is my Regex which fulfills everything but last (repeating pattern) requirement.
(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[.,!@#$%^+=_])(?!.*(.)\1).{8,20}$

Is there a way I can tackle it within above Regex?

A8&x^3@UiA8&x^3@UiA8&x^3@Ui should fail. It's a repeating pattern.

...(?!.*(.{3,}).*\2)... ?

Did you find a regex which achieves that check on its own?

Perhaps like this? ^(?=[^\d\s]*\d)(?=[^\sa-z]*[a-z])(?=[^\sA-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^\s.,!@#$%^+=_]*[.,!@#$%^+=_])(?!.*(\S)\1)(?!.*(\S{2,})\S*\2)\S{8,20}$ See  https://regex101.com/r/BTEWBh/1

[a-z] - it's 2024 and passwords are still restricted to ASCII only? That makes them much easier to crack.

This requirement is so absurd that it feels like they are trolling...

"No repeating words or pattern": what is the difference between a word and a pattern? Do you have an exact definition of these terms in this context? If xyz is such a word, is x such a word as well? Wouldn't that mean that all characters must be unique?

@Thefourthbird your Regex is spot on. It works. May be you can convert it into answer (by providing some string examples).

Assuming your password should not match spaces, you can use \S to match non whitespace characters instead of using a dot.
^(?=[^\d\s]*\d)(?=[^\sa-z]*[a-z])(?=[^\sA-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^\s.,!@#$%^+=_]*[.,!@#$%^+=_])(?!\S*(\S)\1)(?!\S*(\S{2})\S*\2)\S{8,20}$

The pattern matches:

^ Start of string
(?=[^\d\s]*\d) Assert a digit to the right using a negated character class to match optional non whitespace charaters excluding a digit first
(?=[^\sa-z]*[a-z]) Same mechanism for a char a-z
(?=[^\sA-Z]*[A-Z]) Same for a char A-Z
(?=[^\s.,!@#$%^+=_]*[.,!@#$%^+=_]) As well as for a character that you consider special
(?!\S*(\S)\1) Assert that there is no occurrence of 2 consecutive same non whitespace characters to the right
(?!\S*(\S{2})\S*\2) Assert that there is no sequence of 2 of the same non whitespace characters (separated by optional non whitespace characters in between) to the right
\S{8,20}
$ End of string

See a regex demo

That's almost perfect. 1 thing I think of which we can update is don't allow more than 2 repeated same chars, rather than 1. For example Password1! or Challenge1! are valid passwords. BTW, my requirements weren't industry standard, just made up. But we can come up with Industry Standard password which can benefit everyone.

@programmerboy Do you want (?!\S*(\S)\1) to become (?!\S*(\S)\1\1) so it would not allow Passsword1!

Spot on! And changed this (?!\S*(\S{2})\S*\2) to (?!\S*(\S{5})\S*\2), if you want to have something like ProChallengeTotallyProAcceptedFinallyByPro1!

Update you regex pattern of repeating letters(\w) or digits(\d) as follows:
/(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[.,!@#$%^+=_])(?!.*(.)\1)(?![\w\d]\1).{8,20}$/gm

https://regex101.com/r/uMQyZA/1

Thanks, but it doesn't fulfill repeating word/pattern requirements if other requirements are filled. For e.g. if ProPersonPro end in 1! then it will accept it. See @TheFourthBird comment above.

I have update the regex pattern.. please check once @programmerboy

Still not working as expected. In your Regex link above, able to match repeating patterns like ProPersonPro1@ and xyzxyz@1ABC
RegEx provided by @Thefourthbird works!
